# Ubuntu - Symfony 2 - FOSUserBundle

Tags: linux, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have been learning Symfony (strictly Symfony 2.3), I also decided to use FOSUserBundle to my project as the automated login/register system. I downloaded FOSUserBundle (version 2.0 ) using composer. I had lots of problems configuring it locally ( I use Linux Ubuntu 15.10 ). Right now, as I checked: using command line:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

works, but when I try to create a schema or even update, it doesn't work ( I received an information that the update was completed successfully but physically it wasn't ). I haven been searching through google and documentation and probably did something wrong and right now even updating the schema doesn't work (as the command), and the information which I currently receive when I type for instance:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

or

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force is:

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\model\User' does not exist
```

As I realize the above link should be changed into:

```
'FOS\UserBundle\Model\User'
```

and

```
 "Model"
```

should be written starting with the capital letter "M", but I don't know in which file should I do such a modification.

I will paste you below, the contents of the files which I have got. Could you please point me out, in which files and what should I change / add ? Thank you.

```
   AppKernel.php

<?php

  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
  use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

  class AppKernel extends Kernel
  {
     public function registerBundles()
     {
         $bundles = array(
             new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
             new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
             new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
             new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
             new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
             new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
             new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
             new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle                       
                \SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
             new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
             new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
             ); 

             if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'),  
             true)) {
             $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle
             \WebProfilerBundle();
             $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle         
             \SensioDistributionBundle();
             $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle
             \SensioGeneratorBundle();
             }

             return $bundles;
             }

             public function 
             registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
             {

             $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config                   
             /config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
             }
             }
```

,

```
/app/config/config.yml

  imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }

fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
#    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
#model_manager_name: user

framework:
#esi:             ~
#translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_proxies: ~
session:         ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration

assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false 
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    #auto_mapping: ~
    #auto_mapping: FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
  #        auto_mapping: FOS\UserBundle\Model\User: ~

  # Swiftmailer Configuration
   swiftmailer:
  transport: "%mailer_transport%"
   host:      "%mailer_host%"
   username:  "%mailer_user%"
   password:  "%mailer_password%"
   spool:     { type: memory }
                                                                                                                                                               80,1          Dół
```

,

```
/app/config/security.yml


security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        #id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider


            #provider: fos_userbundle
            #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager


            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config    
        instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

   access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

,

```
/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
```

}

Comment: Please double-check that `AppBundle/Entity/User` has `use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;` correctly in there. Please post the complete stacktrace of `app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev -vvv`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, in 'AppBundle/Entity/User' there is the use of 'FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser; ` as it is visible in the piece of code which I pasted above.

Comment: Please do the following. run `app/console cache:clear --env=dev`, then run `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql -vvv` and post the **full** output of the exception message you get.

Comment: The stacktrace of `app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev -vvv` is: `app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev -vvv

                                                           
  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]   
  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\model\User' does not exist  
                                                           
`

Comment: `Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:41               Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:281
`

Comment: Are you sure that's everything that the command outputs? No **line number** where exactly the exception was thrown for example. Ah there is more :-) Add **the complete output** to the question itself please.

Comment: `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:311           Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216`

Comment: Edit the question please. Add the output there as a quote.

Comment: `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:115      Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:59`

Comment: `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php:50           Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:246`

Comment: STOP :) Add the output to the question as a whole please.

Comment: nifr I can't because in each edit I've a limited amount of characters that I can paste into, sorry

Comment: `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:863
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:90`

Comment: `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:115                Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/service_online_newer/app/console:27                 doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]`

Comment: You should just **edit** the question itself and **not** add 20 comments :)

Comment: I know, it would be better but in every comment that I can create, there is a limited amount of characters which I can paste / write, so all the output of the command which you asked for, would cosist too many characters to be pasted in one comment.